# How to call a .NET COM method with an array from delphi using PSafeArray?

Tags: c#, delphi, guid, marshalling, safearray

I have an .NET (4.0) interface which is implemented with a `ServicedComponent` COM+ class:

```
interface DotNetIface
{
    void MethodRef(var System.Guid guid);
    void MethodArray(System.Guid[] guids, params object[] parameters);
    void MethodCStyle([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst=5)]System.Guid[] guids);
}
```

Now I used the Delphi 2007 import wizard to import the type library, and as expected 
I get the following signatures:

```
procedure MethodRef(var guid : TGuid);
procedure MethodArray(guids : PSafeArray);
procedure MethodCStyle(var guids : ClrGuid /* from mscorlib_TLB */);
```

If i now call the "ref" method like this it works fine:

```
procedure CallByRef(guid : TGuid);
var
    test : TGuid;
begin
    test := ...
    comRef.MethodRef(guid);
end;
```

Now I also need the array method

```
procedure CallArray();
var
    localGuid : TGuid;
    arrayVariant : OleVariant;
begin
    arrayVariant := VarArrayCreate([0,4], varVariant /* dont know here */);
    arrayVariant[0] := localGuid; /* compile error, cannot cast implicitly */

    comRef.MethodArray(PSafeArray(TVarData(arrayVariant.VArray)), /* here this object... PSafeArray works actually*/);
end;
```

Now lastly i tried with a c array

```
procedure CallCStyle();
var
    localGuid : TGuid;
    arrayOfGuid : array [0..4] of ClrGuid;
begin
    arrayOfGuid[0] := ClrGuid(localGuid);

    comRef.MethodCStyle(PSafeArray(/* now i dont know put it*/, /* here this object... PSafeArray works actually*/);
end;
```

I seriously dont know how to make this work.
I hope someone has more experience with COM marshalling
thx

Side node:

I found VT_CLSID which i think can be passed for SafeArrayCreate, but I am not sure how to sue that

Comment: anybody an idea how to pass the C-style Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried what you need but a quick search found the following articles:

- [Scripting Your Delphi Applications](http://www.malcolmgroves.com/stories/2004/09/23/scriptingYourDelphiApplications.html) (Shows a Good example of converting a variant array to PSafeArray
- [How to do a SafeArray Access with a DLL for Variants (OLE)](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_2479.asp)
- [The mysteries of PSafeArray](https://web.archive.org/http://blog.virtec.org/2008/07/the-mysteries-of-psafearray/)

Comment: thanks i hope this one helps: http://blog.virtec.org/2008/07/the-mysteries-of-psafearray/
anyway one up for now

Comment: I wonder if its generally possible to pass structs (what GUIDs are in the end anyways), even using a variant

Comment: You can store a list of pointers to the TGuids.   Don't know if that will work for you situation.

Comment: I found that SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_CLSID, 0, count) works,
and using SafeArrayPutElement(psa, indexvar, varname) but i cannot verify, as there is another problem with my system, will post back

Comment: how would i pass a list to a COM server? im not sure that is defined... a i forgot to mention, the COM server is IN_PROC

Comment: All 3 links are not valid anymore. That's why an answer should not consist of just links. I fixed the 3rd link by web.archive.org