# Passing SafeArray from Delphi through to ms-uiautomation libraries

Tags: delphi, microsoft-ui-automation

In relation to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841789/adding-uiautomation-providers-to-delphi-controls-specifically-grids), I now have a partially working implementation that wraps up the TStringGrid, and allows automation to access it.

[Sort of anyway](https://github.com/jhc-systems/DelphiUIAutomation/tree/master/automatedstringgrid).

I need to implement the GetSelection method of the ISelectionProvider, but even though I think I have create a pSafeArray, when I use ms-uiautomation to get the resulting array, it has 0 entries. The code below is definitely called, as I can put a break point and stop it in the method.

I have tried several ways of creating and populating the array, this is my latest (base on a [different question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876320/how-to-call-a-net-com-method-with-an-array-from-delphi-using-psafearray)..

```
function TAutomationStringGrid.GetSelection(out pRetVal: PSafeArray): HResult;
var
  obj : TAutomationStringGridItem;
  outBuffer : PSafeArray;
  offset : integer;
begin
  obj := TAutomationStringGridItem.create(self);
  obj.Row := self.row;
  obj.Column := self.Col;
  obj.Value := self.Cells[self.Col, self.Row];

  offset := 0;
  outBuffer := SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 1);
  SafeArrayPutElement(outBuffer, offset, obj);
  pRetVal := outBuffer;
  result := S_OK;
end;
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong ?

**UPDATE:**

Just to clarify, the automation code that gets called is as follows ..

```
  var
    collection : IUIAutomationElementArray;
  ...
  // Assume that we have a valid pattern
  FSelectionPattern.GetCurrentSelection(collection);
  collection.Get_Length(length);
```

The value returned from Get_Length is 0.

Comment: Do you really mean the array has zero elements, or just that the one element you originally allocated doesn't end up containing the value you think you stored?

Comment: When I use the client code on the 'other-side' of automation, the count of the collection is 0. I will post it as an update above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GetSelection()` implementation is expected to return a `SAFEARRAY` of [`IRawElementProviderSimple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671332.aspx) interface pointers.  However, you are creating a `SAFEARRAY` of `VARIANT` elements instead, but then populating the elements with `TAutomationStringGridItem` object pointers. `SafeArrayPutElement()` requires you to pass it a value that matches the type of the array (which in your code would be a pointer to a `VARIANT` whose value will then be copied). So it makes sense that UIAutomation would not be able to use your malformed array when initializing the `IUIAutomationElementArray` for the client app.

Try something more like this instead:

```
type
  TAutomationStringGridItem = class(TInterfacedObject, IRawElementProviderSimple, IValueProvider, ...)
    ...
  public
    constructor Create(AGrid: TAutomationStringGrid; ARow, ACol: Integer; const AValue: string);
    ...
  end;

constructor TAutomationStringGridItem.Create(AGrid: TAutomationStringGrid; ARow, ACol: Integer; const AValue: string);
begin
  ...
  Self.Row := ARow;
  Self.Column := ACol;
  Self.Value := AValue;
  ...
end;

function TAutomationStringGrid.get_CanSelectMultiple(out pRetVal: BOOL): HResult;
begin
  pRetVal := False;
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TAutomationStringGrid.get_IsSelectionRequired(out pRetVal: BOOL): HResult;
begin
  pRetVal := False;
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TAutomationStringGrid.GetSelection(out pRetVal: PSafeArray): HResult;
var
  intf: IRawElementProviderSimple;
  unk: IUnknown;
  outBuffer : PSafeArray;
  offset, iRow, iCol : integer;
begin
  // get the current selected cell, if any...
  iRow := Self.Row;
  iCol := Self.Col;

  // is a cell selected?
  if (iRow > -1) and (iCol > -1) then
  begin
    // yes...
    intf := TAutomationStringGridItem.Create(Self, iRow, iCol, Self.Cells[iCol, iRow]);
    outBuffer := SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UNKNOWN, 0, 1);
  end else
  begin
    // no ...

    // you would have to check if UIA allows you to return a nil
    // array, possibly with S_FALSE instead of S_OK, so as to
    // avoid having to allocate memory for an empty array...
    {
    // pRetVal is already nil because of 'out'...
    Result := S_FALSE; // or S_OK if S_FALSE is not allowed...
    Exit;
    }

    outBuffer := SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UNKNOWN, 0, 0);
  end;

  if outBuffer = nil then
  begin
    Result := E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    Exit;
  end;

  if intf <> nil then
  begin
    offset := 0;
    unk := intf as IUnknown;
    Result := SafeArrayPutElement(outBuffer, offset, unk);
    if Result <> S_OK then
    begin
      SafeArrayDestroy(outBuffer);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  pRetVal := outBuffer;
end;
```

With that said, `TStringGrid` supports multi-selection, and the output of `GetSelection()` is expected to return an array of all selected items.  So a more accurate implementation would look more like this instead:

```
function TAutomationStringGrid.get_CanSelectMultiple(out pRetVal: BOOL): HResult;
begin
  pRetVal := goRangeSelect in Self.Options;
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TAutomationStringGrid.get_IsSelectionRequired(out pRetVal: BOOL): HResult;
begin
  pRetVal := False;
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TAutomationStringGrid.GetSelection(out pRetVal: PSafeArray): HResult;
var
  intfs: array of IRawElementProviderSimple;
  unk: IUnknown;
  outBuffer : PSafeArray;
  offset, iRow, iCol: Integer;
  R: TGridRect;
begin
  // get the current range of selected cells, if any...
  R := Self.Selection; 

  // are any cells selected?
  if (R.Left > -1) and (R.Right > -1) and (R.Top > -1) and (R.Bottom > -1) then
  begin
    // yes...
    SetLength(intfs, ((R.Right-R.Left)+1)*((R.Bottom-R.Top)+1));
    offset := Low(intfs);
    for iRow := R.Top to R.Bottom do
    begin
      for iCol := R.Left to R.Right do
      begin
        intfs[offset] := TAutomationStringGridItem.Create(Self, iRow, iCol, Self.Cells[iCol, iRow]);
        Inc(offset);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  // you would have to check if UIA allows you to return a nil
  // array, possibly with S_FALSE instead of S_OK, so as to
  // avoid having to allocate memory for an empty array...
  {
  if Length(intfs) = 0 then
  begin
    // pRetVal is already nil because of 'out'...
    Result := S_FALSE; // or S_OK if S_FALSE is not allowed...
    Exit;
  end;
  }

  outBuffer := SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UNKNOWN, Low(intfs), Length(intfs));
  if outBuffer = nil then
  begin
    Result := E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    Exit;
  end;

  for offset := Low(intfs) to High(intfs) do
  begin
    unk := intfs[offset] as IUnknown;
    Result := SafeArrayPutElement(outBuffer, offset, unk);
    if Result <> S_OK then
    begin
      SafeArrayDestroy(outBuffer);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  pRetVal := outBuffer;
  Result := S_OK;
end;
```

Comment: Wow, detailed answer, and it looks like it is much closer what I need, but I've quickly changed my code to use your first example, and when I call the Get_Selection from the client code, the first application now crashes. It might be something I have done, so I'll keep digging, and see where the crash is.

Comment: I get the access violation when adding the unknown object into the SafeArray, whether it is created using the SafeArrayCreateVector or using SafeArrayPutElement.

Comment: OK, I have solved the access violations, I will post the changes as a answer, but accept Remy's as it was pretty much 100% of what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the access violation, and as I can#t post code in a comment, I'll post an answer. The only real difference is that I am casting the IUnknown as a pointer to IUnknown, as this solves the access violation I was seeing.

```
function TAutomationStringGrid.GetSelection(out pRetVal: PSafeArray): HResult;
var
  intf : TAutomationStringGridItem;
  outBuffer : PSafeArray;
  offset : integer;
  unk : IUnknown;
  iRow, iCol : integer;
  Bounds : array [0..0] of TSafeArrayBound;

begin
  pRetVal := nil;
  result := S_FALSE;

  iRow := Self.Row;
  iCol := Self.Col;

  // is a cell selected?
  if (iRow > -1) and (iCol > -1) then
  begin
    intf := TAutomationStringGridItem.create(self, iCol, iRow,  self.Cells[self.Col, self.Row]);

    bounds[0].lLbound := 0;
    bounds[0].cElements := 1;
    outBuffer := SafeArrayCreate(VT_UNKNOWN, 1, @Bounds);

    if intf <> nil then
    begin
      offset := 0;
      unk := intf as IUnknown;
      Result := SafeArrayPutElement(&outBuffer, offset, Pointer(unk)^);
      if Result <> S_OK then
      begin
        SafeArrayDestroy(outBuffer);
        pRetVal := nil;
        result := E_OUTOFMEMORY;
      end
      else
      begin
        pRetVal := outBuffer;
        result := S_OK;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    pRetVal := nil;
    result := S_FALSE;
  end;
end;
```

**UPDATE:** I have edited the code snippet to be inline with Remy's comments below.

Comment: Type-casting an `IUnknown` to a `PUnknown` and then dereferencing it is the COMPLETELY WRONG thing to do. Besides, it is not necessary anyway. Read the [`SafeArrayPutElement()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221283.aspx): "The variant types VT_DISPATCH, VT_UNKNOWN, and VT_BSTR are pointers, and **do not require another level of indirection**."  Your AV is caused by something else.

Comment: Delphi declares `SafeArrayPutElement()` as taking an untyped `const` parameter instead of a `Pointer` like in the real API.  So that is extra indirection being forced by Delphi. Instead of using `PUnknown(unk)^`, try using just `unk^`, or at least `Pointer(unk)^`.

Comment: The unk^ code doesn't compile, but the Pointer(unk)^ does, and still works , so I have changed the snippet above.